# Get count of distinct datetime range values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count

I have two tables in my MySQL database:

```
users_metrics
id | user_id  | login_datetime      | logout_datetime   |
--------------------------------------------------.-----|
1  |    1     |2022-05-04 00:25:16  |2022-05-04 00:30:16|
-----------------------------------------------.--------|
2  |    3     |2022-05-04 10:29:16  |2022-05-04 10:40:16|
--------------------------------------------------------|
3  |    1     |2022-05-04 11:48:16  |2022-05-04 11:49:56|
--------------------------------------------------------|
4  |    3     |2022-05-04 11:58:16  |2022-05-04 12:20:16|
--------------------------------------------------------|
5  |    1     |2022-05-04 16:28:16  |2022-05-04 17:29:56|
--------------------------------------------------------|

files_uploaded
id  | type   | file_upload_datetime | user_id |
-----------------------------------------------
1   |  csv   |2022-05-04 00:29:16   |   1     |
-----------------------------------------------
2   |  csv   |2022-05-04 10:39:16   |   3     |
-----------------------------------------------
3   |  txt   |2022-05-04 11:49:16   |   1     |
-----------------------------------------------
4   |  txt   |2022-05-04 11:59:16   |   3     |
-----------------------------------------------
5   |  csv   |2022-05-04 12:09:16   |   3     |
-----------------------------------------------
6   |  txt   |2022-05-04 12:19:16   |   3     |
-----------------------------------------------
7   |  txt   |2022-05-04 16:29:16   |   1     |
-----------------------------------------------
8   |  csv   |2022-05-04 16:39:16   |   1     |
-----------------------------------------------
9   |  txt   |2022-05-04 16:49:16   |   1     |
-----------------------------------------------
10  |  csv   |2022-05-04 17:29:16   |   1     |
-----------------------------------------------
```

The `users_metrics` table save the login and logout time of a certain user and the `files_uploaded` table records files records uploaded by users.
I am looking for a query that allows obtaining the count of uploaded files within to the datetime range established by the first table.
This would be a view of the result I'm looking for.

```
id | user_id  | login_datetime      | logout_datetime   | total_files_uploaded
--------------------------------------------------.-----|---------------------|
1  |    1     |2022-05-04 00:25:16  |2022-05-04 00:30:16|        1      
-----------------------------------------------.--------|---------------------|
2  |    3     |2022-05-04 10:29:16  |2022-05-04 10:40:16|        1
--------------------------------------------------------|---------------------|
3  |    1     |2022-05-04 11:48:16  |2022-05-04 11:49:56|        1
--------------------------------------------------------|---------------------|
4  |    3     |2022-05-04 11:58:16  |2022-05-04 12:20:16|        3
--------------------------------------------------------|---------------------|
5  |    1     |2022-05-04 16:28:16  |2022-05-04 17:29:56|        3
--------------------------------------------------------|---------------------|
```

Comment: Sorry, the last record of desired table must be 4 in  total_files_uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables based on the user id and login time and then count the uploads:

```
SELECT u.user_id,
       u.login_datetime,
       u.logout_datetime,
       coalesce(count(f.id), 0) total_files_uploaded
  FROM user_metrics u
  LEFT JOIN files_uploaded f
    ON u.user_id = f.user_id
   AND f.file_uploaded_datetime BETWEEN u.login_datetime AND u.logout_datetime
 GROUP BY u.user_id, u.login_datetime, u.logout_datetime;
```

Output:

| user_id | login_datetime | logout_datetime | total_files_uploaded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-04 00:25:16 | 2022-05-04 00:30:16 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-05-04 10:29:16 | 2022-05-04 10:40:16 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-05-04 11:48:16 | 2022-05-04 11:49:56 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-05-04 11:58:16 | 2022-05-04 12:20:16 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-05-04 16:28:16 | 2022-05-04 17:29:56 | 4 |

If a user did not upload any files during their login, this will show 0. If you do not want to show entries for users who did not upload any files you can replace the left join with an inner join and remove the `coalesce`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a great solution. I didn't know about the coalesce function.